# Using strings in INDIRECT function to manipulate cell address

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In trying to use the INDIRECT function shown below.

```
=INDIRECT("B"&SUMPRODUCT((sheet1!C3:Q60=F4)*ROW(sheet1!C3:Q60)))
```

It works when written in the same sheet but when this function is used in a different sheet than the data used in the INDIRECT function it won't work.

according to the `SUMPRODUCT((sheet1!C3:Q60=F4)*ROW(sheet1!C3:Q60))` i want access value from B1,B2,B3...etc.

but when the function runs it returns the value from the active sheet.

I want something like this

`=INDIRECT((sheet1!"B"&SUMPRODUCT((data=AW4)*ROW(data))))`

is this possible to achieve?

Comment: You need to put `sheet1!` into `"B"` in front of the `B`. Then it should work. At least it did for me.
But it would be better to put the `sumproduct` inside an `index` as suggested by @teylyn.

Comment: Multiple answers to your previous question show that you can use `INDEX()` instead of that volatile `INDIRECT()`. Why did you decide to use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't even try to unfrazzle the Sumproduct and why you're using it here, but suffice it to say that Indirect requires text input, which can be stitched together.

If you want to create a reference to Sheet1, column B, and the row number is calculated by your formula, then the syntax for Indirect is

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!B"&<your formula that returns a whole number>)
```

You may want to check your formula in a separate cell to ensure that it really returns the desired row number.

Indirect() has its problems, though. It is volatile an if used a lot, it will slow workbook performance. It may be more efficient to use Index() instead, for example

```
=index(sheet1!B:B,<your formula that returns a whole number>)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to Excel and VBA. Both of the formulas you suggested worked like a charm.